# Unable to install Exchange 2016 - You must use an account that's a member of the Organization Management role

Tags: windows, active-directory, exchange, exchange-2013

I am trying to install exchange 2016.

The organisation has a parent domain called "DOMAIN.LOCAL"
There are currently exchange servers in the following domains only:
"SUBDOMAIN1.DOMAIN.LOCAL"
"SUBDOMAIN2.DOMAIN.LOCAL"

I am in domain "SUBDOMAIN2.DOMAIN.LOCAL".

I am a member of SUBDOMAIN2'.

I am a member of the following groups from SUBDOMAIN2':

- Domain Admins

I am a member of the following groups from "DOMAIN.LOCAL":

- Enterprise Admins
- Exchange Organisation Administrators
- Organisation Management
- Schema Admins

There does not appear to be an Organisation Management group in my subdomain, only the parent domain.

Exchange has full connectivity to two GC DCs on its own domain "SUBDOMAIN2.DOMAIN.LOCAL"

Please see the failed readiness checks:
http://pastebin.com/zUSbgxfc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to some AD schema entries from an update prior to my time at the company that was not completed and not tidied up. After manually going through the AD schema I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Is this the first Exchange 2016 server in the Forest? 
If so, you should prepare the root domain as well as any child domains. 
Do you already have Exchange in the forest? If so, what version?

Comment: There are two 2010 SP3 servers in each subdomain. I have prepared the root domain using the three setup scripts on the exchange media successfully on the root using the /PrepareAllDomains switch.